# pyuic4 ImportError: No module named port_v2.ascii_upper

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to convert a Qt widget created with Qt Designer in a py file using ' `pyuic4`

I just do

```
pyuic4 widget.ui -o ui_widget.py
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyuic4", line 3, in <module>
    import PyQt4.uic.pyuic
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from PyQt4.uic.Compiler import indenter, compiler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py", line 43, in <module>
    from PyQt4.uic.properties import Properties
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/properties.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PyQt4.uic.port_v2.ascii_upper import ascii_upper
ImportError: No module named port_v2.ascii_upper
```

I have been researching the involved modules and I can see this lines in `properties.py` and `pyuic.py`

```
if sys.hexversion >= 0x03000000:
    from PyQt4.uic.port_v3.ascii_upper import ascii_upper
else:
    from PyQt4.uic.port_v2.ascii_upper import ascii_upper
```

(I can see in Riverbank's page that there are a branch with v2 ascii, but I haven't installed)

If I do in command line:
python (v2.7.12)

```
>>> import sys
>>> print hex(sys.hexversion)
0x2070cf0
>>>
```

Then I do the same in python3 (3.5.2)

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (hex(sys.hexversion))
0x30502f0
>>>
```

Well...looks as if pyuic4 calls a python 2 version. But I don't know what I need for execute pyuic4 with python3

Another data related with PyQt4 (I don't know if it's useful):

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> print ((QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR, QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR))
('4.11.4', '4.8.7')
>>>
```

**Edit:**

This is installed from `pyqt4-dev-tools` package (linux mint).
If I try to install using PIP I get this error:

```
pip3 install pyuic4
```

> Collecting pyuic4
>
> Could not find a version that
>   satisfies the requirement pyuic4 (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for pyuic4 You are using pip version 8.1.1, however
>   version 19.0.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the
>   'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

**Edit2 and posible solution**

Thanks to `@ekhumoro` I've got solved my problem. This is the content of `/usr/bin/pyuic4`

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# there's no main function, so just import the module
import PyQt4.uic.pyuic
```

I need to point to python3, so I've just modify the first line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share the pip command you used to install pyuic4? You need to make sure you use pip from python3. virtualenv is especially helpful in such cases

Comment: Thx. I have installed pyuic4 from pyqt4-dev-tools package (linux mint), not from pip. If I try to do that using pip I get another error (I'll edit the question for add that information)

Comment: @user3733164 What specific version of python is executed when you run `/usr/bin/python` on your system?

Comment: @user3733164 Why are you using pyqt4? Both qt4 and pyqt4 are obsolete legacy libraries that are no longer officially supported. You should use qt5/pyqt5 if you can.

Comment: @ekhumoro, well, it works with pyuic5!. Thanks a lot. Anyway a three years ago more or less I developed any plugins for QGIS, and I built the gui with pyuic4. This is the reason because I was trying to use that. If I have problem with those plugins I'll ask more specific question related. Any question, how can I mark your answer like the solver answer?

Comment: @user3733164 Which one? If your `/usr/bin/python` points to `python2`, you could make a copy of the `pyuic4` script and edit it to use `python3` (and then create an alias for it or something). Then again, if you have existing pyqt4 code that works with python3, it could be quite easy to port it to pyqt5 - but it's not always completely straightforward.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your first question. Yes, my ```/usr/bin/python``` points to ```python2```. Your solution sounds great, but...how could do it that? I mean, edit a copy of ```pyuic4``` to use ```python3```?

Comment: @user3733164 It's just a shell script, so open it in an editor and change `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, very thanks. It solved my problem!